# Call async method from magic method

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I use MongoDB and Motor as driver. I wrote simple Model class. After init I'm need to insert this record in DB (`self._toDb`), but I can't because python doesn't allow to make __magic__ with async. I tried to use this code `app.loop.call_soon(self._toDb)`, but it is never executed. Creating new event loop for this coroutine will raise exception. Help me please.

```
class Model(abc.ABC):
    collection = db['Model']
    fields = {}

    def __init__(self, data, manual=False, doSave=True, _id=None):
        super(Model, self).__setattr__('manual', manual)
        super(Model, self).__setattr__('data', data)
        if  _id:
            super(Model, self).__setattr__('_id', _id)
        else:
            # does not work
            app.loop.call_soon(self._toDb)


    async def _toDb(self):
        super(Model, self).__setattr__('_id', await self.collection.insert(self.data) )
        print("inserted to db")
```

UPD:
I tried to use  ensure_future, it seems to work, but it raises exceptions

```
Exception in callback <Task pending coro=<Model._toDb() running at /home/oleg/python/zapdos/app/models.py:31> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]>>
handle: <Handle <Task pending coro=<Model._toDb() running at /home/oleg/python/zapdos/app/models.py:31> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uvloop/cbhandles.pyx", line 55, in uvloop.loop.Handle._run (uvloop/loop.c:38238)
TypeError: 'Task' object is not callable
```

Comment: ... why are you using `__setattr__`?

Comment: I store all data in dict self.data, \_\_setattr\_\_ and \_\_getattr\_\_ provide logic for that.

Comment: It just doesn't work.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438163/setting-a-descriptor-in-python3-5-asynchronously