# How I can call asyncio code from sync function which called from other async function?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I need call async code from sync code which called from other async function

I try to do [Setting a descriptor in python3.5 asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438163/setting-a-descriptor-in-python3-5-asynchronously) but this answer didn't help me

```py
async def first():
    return second()


def second():
    # TODO: In this function I want to call function thrird,
    #       and I want to call it asynchronous!
    #       This function MUST be syncronious (for example __get__)


async def third():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        first(),
        first()
    )
    # must work 1 second


asyncio.run(main())
```

This code must work 1 sec, not 2

Comment: No no no no. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34681101/4727702

Comment: It's about C#, not Python. Is in python this feature exist or not?

Comment: It is about the difference between asynchronous and multithreading execution. Your assumption about 1 second is not correct.

Comment: It's not assumption -- I ask about opportunity :) And if I can't do this, this is sad story